# A Question on the "rewinding" technique in secure computation

Tags: provable-security, multiparty-computation, universal-composability

Consider secure two-party computation against malicious adversaries in the standalone model.
I know that the "rewinding" technique can be used to extract the corrupt party's input, e.g., in $\Sigma$-protocol or interactive commitment.
I am curious about whether this technique can be generally applied to secure computation for input extraction.
For example, can the simulator rewind the internal real-world adversary back to some early "snapshot" **after the two parties' outputs in the real-world execution (which is run on the dummy input for the honest party and the real-world adversary's input to be extracted) are settled**?

If so, does it imply a possible simulation strategy where the simulator extracts the corrupt party's input by using the dummy input and the honest party's output in the real-world execution?

It would be really appreciated if someone could give me any hint on the restrictions of this technique.
Currently, I know from [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/60741/secure-computation-reactive-functionalities-in-the-hybrid-model-for-standalone) how this technique is applied to reactive functionalities.
I also know that this technique is not allowed in the UC model.